# DNS is not updating on operating systems that have already viewed website

Tags: dns

I recently ( > 24 hrs ago) changed the nameserver for my web app. On a couple of my computers (on different routers but same ISP) that have previously viewed the website, the DNS settings have not changed. I assume the problem has to do with the old record being cached somewhere, but I'm not sure where that is.

I first noticed the problem on my work computer while on Ubuntu in both Firefox and Chrome. While in Ubuntu I restarted the router's DNS cache. The problem was fixed.

Then I booted my work computer into Windows, and the old settings were still being used. I restarted the router's DNS cache again and ran ipconfig /flushdns, but the old DNS settings are still being used.

I also checked my computer at home, and the old settings were also being used there.

Any ideas what the problem might be? If it is a router caching issue, how long should it take to refresh the cache? (and why aren't the changes effective on Windows?)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand from your question your app is still accessible from these computers as you have not changed your hosting service. so things will be updated with time you don't need to worry about it.

> Then I booted my work computer into Windows, and the old settings were still being used.

In windows you can try running this command in cmd:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

this will clear the DNS cache.

Comment: Oops... I was editing my post to mention that I tried ipconfig /flushdns. Actually the app is inaccessible on Windows because to change the name servers with my domain registrar, I had to get rid of the old CNAME settings pointing to my heroku app. So now all I see on my Windows machines is the 1&1 domain parking page.

Comment: I'd be open to suggestions on how to get 1&1 to point/redirect to my app instead of the parking page.

Comment: have you changed your domain name or its just the DNS server that you are changing

Comment: Just the name server. I switched it from the default 1&1 server to the CloudFlare name servers.